How do you limit the scope in HTML?
This answer to this question is probably extremely obvious and I'm just not seeing it, but how do you make sure certain style attributes only apply to one element when referencing the tag that they use.
I currently have a pure css Collapsible I snagged from DigitalOcean and I am using Ember Components.
The code uses a checkbox to activate the Collapsible - which means it hides the checkbox in the style tag referencing the input tag:
<style>
    input[type='checkbox'] {
      display: none;
    }
</style>

...

<input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">

However, in doing so, I end up with all the other checkboxes on the page becoming hidden as well.
(And this style tag lives inside the .hbs Component file for the dropdown, dunno if that changes anything)
How can I target just the Collapsible specifically for hiding the checkbox?
Also let me know if there is any other information that might be helpful :)
So far I've tried wrapping this attribute inside another attribute:
 .hide-checkbox {
    input[type='checkbox'] {
      display: none;
    }
  }

But that just gave me a text input box instead of a checkbox.
I checked this post as well, but it did not mention or clarify anything about wrapping the attribute, which is why I asked a separate question.

Why not use the id? Semantic and valid HTML can only have one element with a unique id, so why not #collapsible { display:none } or if the HTML is not semantic (which it should be) you could do #collapsible.[type="checkbox"] { ... } which would only select elements with the #collapsible id, that also have the same type value attribute.

Oh okay, I'm just starting this whole software development thing and that is super helpful, I didn't think of that at all, thank you for your help :)

This question is similar to: CSS Selector that applies to elements with two classes. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@disinfor I edited my question to clarify :) hopefully that makes more sense :)

Your question was perfectly clear, since my comment answered it (it's the same as the answer below). We tend to mark questions as similar to older questions (with answers) when they could answer the current question. Although not exactly the same, the similar question could potentially lead to the answer you're looking for. In this example, the similar question talks about multiple selectors (which would have solved this question), but may also allow the original asker to have an "ah ha" moment.

Oh I see, thank you for clarifying further, that makes more sense now :)

You can target elements in a variety of ways.  In your case, if the element has an id, use that since id should be unique anyway:


#collapsible {
  display: none;
}
<input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">




So far I've tried wrapping this attribute inside another attribute

That would also work, if your element is wrapped in a matching element:


.hide-checkbox {
  input[type='checkbox'] {
    display: none;
  }
}
<div class="hide-checkbox">
  <input id="collapsible" class="toggle" type="checkbox">
</div>



Or, if you don't want to introduce a wrapping element, use that class on the target element itself:


input.hide-checkbox[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}
<input id="collapsible" class="toggle hide-checkbox" type="checkbox">



